# Reapeating task from workflow with Mod formula

Tags: workflow, formula-field, time-dependent-workflow

I would like to add two fields on a contact record. One date, "Start Date", and one integer, "Call Frequency (months)". I will then have a formula field, "Days until next call" that evaluates to:

```
(Call_Frequency__c*30)-MOD(TODAY()-Start_Date__c,30)
```

Now, each day that number will count down from 30*frequency (so if you set at 2 months, it will start at 60 and count down)

I would to verify that this formula changing counts as editing the contact. If so, this means that I can use this formula as a trigger for a workflow rule. Everytime "Days until next call" is equal to one, create a task with a due date of trigger date + 1.

Will this work? I've verified that the trigger works, but only by changing the start date. I want to check if TODAY() changing will also trigger the workflow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It does not count as an "edit", because the values are calculated in real-time. You should be able to build two workflow rules, one that has a time-delay edit, and the other that essentially undoes the time-delay edit and performs some other action (e.g. creating a task), by way of "recursive updates" on workflow rules. You also need to "edit" each record at least once after activating the rules to make sure they place the records in to the time-delay queue.

Comment: Makes sense :) Hopefully at some point we'll be able to just start a recurring task from a workflow